# Why do the residuals from a factor analysis have mean zero?

Tags: factor-analysis

The model is given below:
\begin{align}
y_1 - \mu_1 &= \lambda_{11}f_1 + \lambda_{12}f_2 + \dots + \lambda_{1m}f_m + \epsilon_1  \\
y_2 - \mu_2 &= \lambda_{21}f_1 + \lambda_{22}f_2 + \dots + \lambda_{2m}f_m + \epsilon_2  \\
 &\vdots  \\
y_p - \mu_p &= \lambda_{p1}f_1 + \lambda_{p2}f_2 + \dots + \lambda_{pm}f_m + \epsilon_p  \\
\ \\
\text{For }j &= 1,2,\ \dots,\ m  \\
E(f_j) &= 0,\ {\rm Var}(f_j) = 1,\ {\rm Cov}(f_j, f_k) = 0,\ j \neq k  \\
\ \\
\text{For }i &= 1,\ 2,\ \dots,\ p  \\
E(\epsilon_i) &= 0,\ {\rm Var}(\epsilon_i) = \psi_i, {\rm Cov}(\epsilon_i,\epsilon_k) = 0, i \neq k
\end{align}

I understand why each $\epsilon_i$ have different variances, but why do they have $0$ mean?

Comment: How would you identify the $\mu_i$ otherwise?

Comment: I mean why not $\phi_i$?

Comment: You lost me there--there are no references to any "$\phi_i$" in your post.

Comment: I meant why not 1,2 or some other number.

Comment: I think $\epsilon_i$ is just like an error, so they can follow any distribution, don't they?

Comment: So, we want to have $E(y_i - \mu_i) = 0$, and $E(f_j)=0$, then $E(\epsilon_i)$ should be $0$. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an assumption of the model. Think of it this way, in your model you have one of your equations written as:
\begin{align}
y_1 - \mu_1 &= \lambda_{11}f_1 + \lambda_{12}f_2 + \dots + \lambda_{1m}f_m + \epsilon_1 
\end{align}
The intention of writing something like this is that you think $y_1-\mu_1$ can be modeled as a linear combinations of $m$ factors. If this is true, then in the best case (probably impossible) you will get that the error of your model is 0. However, since you know it is almost impossible to find statistical models that work 100% of the time (otherwise you have determinism), then you should get an error close to zero, and since the error is a random variable, you can assume that it has a first moment (i.e mean) equal to zero.